# Interpreting the output of cox.zph() plots

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model

I have large data (n = 12000) and I have to decide, is the PH assumption actually violated or this is just due to the high number of subjects.

```
                  chisq df         p
age              22.580  1 0.0000020
sex               0.073  1     0.787
comorbidity_long  3.814  1     0.051
GLOBAL           29.793  3 0.0000015
```

[image]

If there a point in trying to interpret the temporal changes and if they are clinically unimportant/marginal, I should not care about the PH assumption? On what scale the y-axis on this plot is and is it meaningfully interpretable?

Comment: The mean of the residuals should be approximately 0, so it is strange to have the purple curve entirely above 0. But, I think it is happening because the purple curve is the estimated median of the distribution as a function of time. The distribution is skewed in this case so the mean is different from the median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a statistically significant violation of PH; The question about whether you have a practically important violation depends on your understanding of the underlying subject matter.

The smoothed curve shows how the estimated coefficient for `age` changes with survival time. To my eye, it looks like the estimates change from a bit under 0.1 per unit of `age` at early survival times to about 0.05 per unit of `age` at later survival times. Are those differences in the `age` coefficient over time large enough to matter for this study? Does this violation with respect to `age` matter in terms of the overall goal of the study, which presumably isn't in the effect of `age` per se? Only you and your colleagues can answer that, based on the subject matter.

Improper specification of the form of a continuous predictor can also lead to a PH violation; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379416/28500) for an example. With this number of cases, consider a flexible spline-based treatment of the `age` predictor, rather than the simple linear coefficient you currently use. Splines provide a flexible approach that allow the data themselves to tell you the proper functional form.

Comment: Can you explain more about how to interpret the plot? Should the scaled residuals be approximately normal with variance equal to $1/V_i$ and should the poster ignore the numbers on the y-axis or do they mean anything? The purple curve seems to be flat but it seems to have intercept greater than 0. What does the purple curve tell them?

Comment: @JohnL the y-axis represents what coefficient estimates for `age` would be, based on different survival times along the x-axis. Individual residuals aren't so important in this plot (except for outliers); the smoothed trend in coefficient values over time matters. If PH holds that smoothed trend should be flat; it isn't quite flat here, dropping a bit at later survival times. See the documentation for the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) and its [time-dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for more.