# Assessing proportional hazards assumption: p-value from coxzph() vs. visual inspection of plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals with time

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

The `coxzph()` function in the R package `Survival` shows a significant p-value for violation of the proportional hazards assumption for a covariate included in a Cox model. However, a plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals against time (below) shows no obvious correlation. For the sake of clarity, the covariate is categorized (there are three categories).

Could the significant p-value be related to a large sample size (500000) and number of events (~3000) allowing detection of a small unimportant correlation? If so, is it acceptable to make a judgement based on the plot rather than the `coxzph()` output and include the covariate in the model (i.e. without stratifying or adding an interaction with time)?

[image: Scaled Schoenfeld residuals against time]

Comment: With this many cases, showing the individual residuals makes it hard to see the overall pattern. Please re-plot without the individual residuals, and emphasize the line showing the smoothed estimate of Beta(t). Also, change the y-axis limits to show more clearly the actual range over which Beta(t) seems to be changing. Right now, the y-axis goes from -10 to +10, representing hazard ratios between $5 x 10^-5$ to 22000! Center the y-axis at the overall estimate for the coefficient, and show maybe +/- 1 unit beyond in each direction.

Comment: Also, if this is a continuous covariate, you might be better off fitting with a flexible continuous fit (e.g., restricted cubic splines) first. Mis-specification of the functional form of a covariate can show up [like a PH violation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379416/28500). If you want to simplify your presentation of the results, you can illustrate thereafter with examples having different particular values.